# Appendix letter position

Tags: sectioning, appendices

`\appendix \section{Appendix}` gives me "A Appendix".  How can I get "Appendix A"

Comment: Which documentclass are you using? Normally you write the name of the appendix in the sectioning command, not the word "Appendix". Anyway, the `titlesec` package should be helpful to change this.

Comment: I'm using article.  I just want section headings "Appendix A" then "Appendix B" and for these to appear in the contents correcty.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 9):

the only way i can see to do this is to redefine the `\section` command either just before or just after `\appendix`.  this should do it:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries Appendix }}
\makeatother
```

(this is simply a cut-and-paste of the definition from `article.cls` with `\newcommand` changed to `\renewcommand` and "`Appendix`" added at the end.  be careful with the spacing; you have to supply the space after "Appendix"; it won't be done for you.)

using this, just input `\appendix \section{}`.  this is admittedly brute force, but the question has been hanging around for a while with no answer, so something is probably better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm copy-pasting the answer from [yoda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616736/yoda) at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690679/add-appendix-before-a-in-thesis-toc). It is an exact answer of this question.

---

You can easily achieve what you want using the `appendix` package. Here's a sample file that shows you how. The key is the `titletoc` option when calling the package. It takes whatever value you've defined in `\appendixname` and the default value is `Appendix`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
  \chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}

 The output looks like
```

[image]

Comment: We have a [policy](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) against just posting links. I appreciate that in this case, the danger of link rot is less worrying since it's a link to another stack exchange site, but I think it's important to encourage good practices.